# Unable to convert ByteArrayResource to Multipart file in Java

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, multipart, spring-rest

I am trying to send Multipart file using Rest api. The catch is before sending the file I am zipping the content and adding it to HttpEntity. So when it reaches to the endpoint, the Multipart is unable to parse it and giving an exception.

MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present".

Need help to solve this problem.

```
public void sendRecord(final byte[] compressedRecord) {

           final MultiValueMap<String, Object> multipartReq = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

           {
                final HttpHeaders zipHdr = new HttpHeaders();
                zipHdr.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
                final HttpEntity<ByteArrayResource> entity = new HttpEntity<>(new ByteArrayResource(compressedRecord), zipHdr);
                multipartReq.add(AppConstants.MULTIPART_FILE_LABEL, entity);
                log.info("multipartReq {}", multipartRequest);
            }

            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setAcceptCharset(Collections.singletonList(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(multipartRequest, headers);
            this.retryableRestOperations.exchange(this.url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, Void.class);
}
```

Comment: What is the constant value of 'AppConstants.MULTIPART_FILE_LABEL'?

Comment: Its "file". Same as the name I have given in the controller class

Comment: multiparmultipartRequest.add("file", new FileSystemResource(entity));           entity should be of type 'File'.

Comment: FileSystemResource does not have a constructor accepting HttpEntity as argument. Should I convert byte[] to file and try?

Comment: yes. It accepts File type. So you can create your Zip file and use it as the constructor value. Refer this to create a zip file. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590362/how-can-i-create-multipart-compressed-zip-file-in-java]

Comment: Sure IMS. Let me try.

Comment: @IMS , can't I send the compressed data through HttpEntity ?